# Your role instances have recycled a number of times during an update or upgrade operation

Tags: azure, azure-web-roles

I am trying to deploy a Cloud Service with 1 Web Role to Azure.

When I do so, I get this message:

```
Your role instances have recycled a number of times during an update or upgrade operation. This indicates that the new version of your service or the configuration settings you provided when configuring the service prevent the role instances from running. Verify your code does not throw unhandled exceptions and that your configuration settings are correct and then start another update or upgrade operation.
```

The project runs just fine locally, and I'm having a hard time figuring out how to start debugging this issue. Are there any common problems that cause this message or steps to figure out what is causing it?

Answer (score 3):

See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/kwill/windows-azure-paas-compute-diagnostics-data.  This will walk through all of the diagnostic data available as well as how to troubleshoot the most common issues.

Comment: In other words, "Go ask someone else."

Comment: Link redirects to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/ now.
Was it supposed to link to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/kwill/windows-azure-paas-compute-diagnostics-data ?

Comment: Yes, that is the new link Shelby, thanks for pointing it out.  Updated the answer.

Answer (score 2):

We also had this annoying problem and in our case:

1. We use local storage, but it wasn't defined in service definition (or Worker Role's properties)
2. Our worker role project has reference to a service project which has reference to data layer project. But, the worker role project doesn't have reference to the data layer project. As soon as we added reference to data layer project in worker role project, it deploys successfully.

Problem #1 can be easily noticed if you **first run the project in your local machine**. Exception will be thrown.

Problem #2, however, is more difficult, mainly because it runs just fine in local machine. After 5 days of trouble shooting, we finally found the problem. So, **check all references and try to add sub-reference projects, those that are referenced by other references.**

Answer (score 1):

We had similar problem, and it was due to some DDLs failed to load. (due to different version from the one MS have deployed to the VM)

Try to set CopyLocal to "true" for all the References in the project, and re-deploy.

Answer (score 0):

I would either remote desktop to the cloud instance and review the Windows Event Logs for exceptions or redeploy with IntelliTrace Enabled. If you choose the later, you can download the IntelliTrace logs from Visual Studio and debug

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/ff683671.aspx

Answer (score 0):

One way to find out the actual error is to click on the " 1 instance" at the top of Dashboard after trying to deploy your web role. It will tell you the status of the role instance. The status should include more information about the type of error which blocks your deployment.

It depends on what your case is. For me, the status claimed that I had an unhandled Security exception. After some investigation, it turned out that under my role's OnStart(), I tried to create a event source. However, Azure service doesn't have the permission to create an event source.

For more possible issues, check http://blogs.msdn.com/b/kwill/archive/2013/09/06/troubleshooting-scenario-3-role-stuck-in-busy.aspx

Answer (score 0):

For me, the issue was with my SQL Azure DB firewall rules. My Azure SQL Database servers are not set to "Allow Access to Azure services", so I have to explicitly list IPs that are allowed.

I discovered this after wrapping my code in a try/catch that swallowed all exceptions, refactoring my OnStart() and RunAsync() methods, and setting all my references to Copy Local = True. None of that worked, then I saw that I had this line in my RunAsync() method:

```
log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator.Configure();
```

I am using the AdoNetAdapter for log4net and connecting to an Azure SQL DB for logging, so that led me to check the firewall rules.

Answer (score 0):

For me, I had some differing version of nuget packages in my various projects.  Once I consolidated everything to the same version(s), it worked fine.

Answer (score -1):

With the release of Windows Azure SDK version 2.2 for Visual Studio 2012 and 2013, Now you can [Remote Debug Cloud Resources within Visual Studio](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2013/10/22/windows-azure-announcing-release-of-windows-azure-sdk-2-2-with-lots-of-goodies.aspx).

Once your cloud service is published and running live in the cloud, you can simply set a breakpoint in your local source code. This may help you in digging out what's going wrong!

Comment: The user states his issue is with deploying not the app running