# Unable to Upgrade Deployment in Azure

Tags: azure, tfsbuild

I am getting the following error when I run Continuous Deployment in TFS:

> The polling operation Upgrade Deployment failed with the error: (400)
>   BadRequest.
>
> Error Code: BadRequest
>
> Message: Your role instances have recycled a number of times during an
>   update or upgrade operation. This indicates that the new version of
>   your service or the configuration settings you provided when
>   configuring the service prevent the role instances from running.
>   Verify your code does not throw unhandled exceptions and that your
>   configuration settings are correct and then start another update or
>   upgrade operation.

Also, I have checked the VM on where the build is and on the Microsoft.Compute.VMAccessAgent extensions I got this error:

> Cannot update Remote Desktop Connection settings for built-in
>   Administrator account. Error: Object reference not set to an instance
>   of an object.

Has anyone come across this? The build continues to run and does not stop.

Comment: If you do the Upgrade Deployment operation directly on Azure portal, do you get the same error message? If so, your issue is related to Azure. Please check my reply below for further information on how to trouble-shoot it.

Answer (score 0):

The "*Your role instances have recycled a number of times during an update or upgrade operation*" error message is always prompted when  Windows Azure SDK is upgraded. The workaround is go to Project Properties and upgrade to the correct version SDK.

Please have a check on this blog for the thoughts on how to trouble shoot it:
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/cie/archive/2013/12/21/role-just-recycles-after-sdk-upgrade.aspx

Also a blog series about troubleshooting on common issues: [Your role instances have recycled a number of times during an update or upgrade operation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19668460/your-role-instances-have-recycled-a-number-of-times-during-an-update-or-upgrade)